# why is a React class component converted to functional component with hooks not picking up state in event handler on document

Tags: reactjs

I tried to refactor the code [here](https://gist.github.com/ZackKnopp/40fc0691feb03f0fba3e25e7353b73ae) using a functional component instead of a class component and am seeing that the state the copy event handler picks up is the initial state. I tried adding other copy event handlers and found the same behavior and was wondering how I can address this so that it can pick up the current state instead.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { range } from 'lodash';
import ReactDataGrid from 'react-data-grid'; // Tested with v5.0.4, earlier versions MAY NOT HAVE cellRangeSelection


import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MyDataGrid />
    </div>
  );
}


const columns = [
  { key: 'id', name: 'ID', editable: true },
  { key: 'title', name: 'Title', editable: true },
  { key: 'count', name: 'Complete', editable: true },
  { key: 'sarah', name: 'Sarah', editable: true },
  { key: 'jessica', name: 'Jessica', editable: true },
];

const initialRows = Array.from(Array(1000).keys(), (_, x) => (
  { id: x, title: x * 2, count: x * 3, sarah: x * 4, jessica: x * 5 }
));

const defaultParsePaste = str => (
  str.split(/\r\n|\n|\r/)
    .map(row => row.split('\t'))
);

const MyDataGrid = props => {
    const [state, setState] = useState({
      rows: initialRows,
      topLeft: {},
      botRight: {},
    });

    useEffect(() => {
    // Copy paste event handler
    document.addEventListener('copy', handleCopy);
    document.addEventListener('paste', handlePaste);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('copy', handleCopy);
      document.removeEventListener('paste', handlePaste);
    }
  }, [])

  const rowGetter = (i) => {
    const { rows } = state;
    return rows[i];
  }

  const updateRows = (startIdx, newRows) => {
    setState((state) => {
      const rows = state.rows.slice();
      for (let i = 0; i < newRows.length; i++) {
        if (startIdx + i < rows.length) {
          rows[startIdx + i] = { ...rows[startIdx + i], ...newRows[i] };
        }
      }
      return { rows };
    });
  }

  const handleCopy = (e) => {
    console.debug('handleCopy Called');
    e.preventDefault();
    const { topLeft, botRight } = state;


    // Loop through each row
    const text = range(topLeft.rowIdx, botRight.rowIdx + 1).map(
      // Loop through each column
      rowIdx => columns.slice(topLeft.colIdx, botRight.colIdx + 1).map(
        // Grab the row values and make a text string
        col => rowGetter(rowIdx)[col.key],
      ).join('\t'),
    ).join('\n');
    console.debug('text', text);
    e.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', text);
  }

  const handlePaste = (e) => {
    console.debug('handlePaste Called');
    e.preventDefault();
    const { topLeft } = state;

    const newRows = [];
    const pasteData = defaultParsePaste(e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain'));

    console.debug('pasteData', pasteData);

    pasteData.forEach((row) => {
      const rowData = {};
      // Merge the values from pasting and the keys from the columns
      columns.slice(topLeft.colIdx, topLeft.colIdx + row.length)
        .forEach((col, j) => {
          // Create the key-value pair for the row
          rowData[col.key] = row[j];
        });
      // Push the new row to the changes
      newRows.push(rowData);
    });

    console.debug('newRows', newRows);

    updateRows(topLeft.rowIdx, newRows);
  }

  const onGridRowsUpdated = ({ fromRow, toRow, updated, action }) => {
    console.debug('onGridRowsUpdated!', action);
    console.debug('updated', updated);
    if (action !== 'COPY_PASTE') {
      setState((state) => {
        const rows = state.rows.slice();
        for (let i = fromRow; i <= toRow; i++) {
          rows[i] = { ...rows[i], ...updated };
        }
        return { rows };
      });
    }
  };

  const setSelection = (args) => {
    console.log('setting... >>', args)
    setState({
      ...state,
      topLeft: {
        rowIdx: args.topLeft.rowIdx,
        colIdx: args.topLeft.idx,
      },
      botRight: {
        rowIdx: args.bottomRight.rowIdx,
        colIdx: args.bottomRight.idx,
      },
    });
  };


    const { rows } = state;
    return (
      <div>
        <ReactDataGrid
          columns={columns}
          rowGetter={i => rows[i]}
          rowsCount={rows.length}
          onGridRowsUpdated={onGridRowsUpdated}
          enableCellSelect
          minColumnWidth={40}
          cellRangeSelection={{
            onComplete: setSelection,
          }}
        />
      </div>

    );

}

export default MyDataGrid;


const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter that you pass to useEffect tells react to skip the effect unless one of the items in the array has changed. You passed in an empty array, so other than the initial render, it will never update. Thus, you set up the event listeners with functions that have the original state in their closure, and nothing else.

To get it to update as state changes, either remove the array, or fil it with variables that your code depends on:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('copy', handleCopy);
    document.addEventListener('paste', handlePaste);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('copy', handleCopy);
      document.removeEventListener('paste', handlePaste);
    }
  }, [state])
```

Comment: that was intentional since the event listeners should only be added on initial load like how the class component version does it and doesn't add another event listener in componentDidUpdate.  If I have copy and paste event listeners being added every time state changes, then I'm pretty sure that that would lead to a memory leak.  

Still, I tried your solution and that didn't resolve the issue

Comment: The memory leak is prevented by the teardown function which you've already written that removes the event listeners, so don't worry about that. Anyway, sorry my suggestion didn't work for you.

Comment: the teardown function would only work when the component unmounts, which in this scenario, will not necessarily happen as many times as state changes, so a memory leak would occur.

Comment: That's incorrect. Every time the effect is run, the previous instance of the effect gets torn down first. So teardown happens on every update and also on unmount. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#cleaning-up-an-effect

Comment: I'm sorry!  For some reason, I needed to reload and it now runs.  thank you!